# Extract text between commas and quotes, ignoring escaped characters in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I need to separate the following string : `"ABC", err, "%. Exiting." , "Use options \"-a,-a,-s,-t\" OR \"-aa,-bb\".",0,-1,""` 
into the characters between the commas and quotes. I am using the following regular expression in perl : `\(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)\g`. This gives me the following output, which has an extra space identified.

```
"ABC"
err
"%. Exiting."
  #[Unwanted Match]
"Use options \"-a,-a,-s,-t\" OR \"-aa,-bb\"."
0
-1
"" #[This Match is required]
```

How can I ignore this space, preserving the empty string in quotes quotes at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions. Whilst they can do it, you're matching nested things and that at best makes the regex really messy and complicated. Use a parser. Like  `Text::ParseWords`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

my $line = '"ABC", err, "%. Exiting." , "Use options \"-a,-a,-s,-t\" OR \"-aa,-bb\".",0,-1,""';
my @words = parse_line( ',', 1, $line );
print join ("\n", @words );
```

Which gives:

```
"ABC"
 err
 "%. Exiting." 
 "Use options \"-a,-a,-s,-t\" OR \"-aa,-bb\"."
0
-1
""
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Sobrique's solution. If you want still want to use regular expression, you need to choose where you want the extra white space to go. Use this to trim all your lines:

```
/\s*(".*?"|[^",]+)\s*(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g
```

If you want to allow for spaces before and after your quotes you can have the regular expression like this:

```
/(\s*".*?"\s*|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g
```

Both will remove the unwanted hit, but gives different results.

Comment: I think this also serves to prove my point. Whilst you can do it with regex (and this illustrates how) the result is ... somewhat difficult to follow, and you'll end up wondering what you were thinking in 6 months time :).